# Fire multiple notification everyday

Tags: java, android, android-workmanager

I want to fire 5 notifications everyday at specific time (t1,t2,t3,t4,t5). These time variables i have to take from inside JSON everyday because each day they are different values. The notification must be fired even the Android App is in background.

MyWorker Class

```
public Result doWork() {
    sendNotification();
    return Result.SUCCESS;
}

public void sendNotification() {
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    //If on Oreo then notification required a notification channel.
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("default", "Default", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }

    NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), "default")
            .setContentTitle("Hello")
            .setContentText("there")
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

    notificationManager.notify(1, notification.build());
}
```

---

My LoginActivity

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    Window w = getWindow();
    w.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
    w.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}

btnLogin = findViewById(R.id.login_button);

mWorkManager = WorkManager.getInstance();
mRequest2 = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(MyWorker.class,15, TimeUnit.MINUTES).build();

btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mWorkManager.enqueue(mRequest2);
    }
});
```

}

I need some help to clarify. Should i use two workers, one to take data from json everyday at specific time and after that to fire 5 notifications with the specific timer for each or how can i solve that. I really appreciate your time. Thank you!

====================================================================

I also tried this after a day but doesn't work. Combined Service, BroadcastReceiver and AlarmManager.

public class MyService extends Service {

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, ShortTimeEntryReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, intent1,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES,
            pendingIntent);

    return START_STICKY;
}
```

}

And BroadcastReceiver

public class ShortTimeEntryReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    sendNotification(context);
    context.startService(new Intent(context,MyService.class));

}

public void sendNotification(Context context) {
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("default", "Default", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }

    NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "default")
            .setContentTitle("Hello")
            .setContentText("there")
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

    notificationManager.notify(1, notification.build());
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

WorkManager doesn't guarantee running your worker at exact time. You need to use AlarmManager with [`setExact()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager#setExact(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)).

Personally, I would look into the option to use a [High Priority FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#setting-the-priority-of-a-message) sent to the app at the right time from a server.
This is much more battery friendly for the user and you have much less constraints on modern Android due to battery optimizations.